# FTPClient issue literal command from Java (Apache)

Tags: java, apache, ftp, ftp-client

Is it possible to issue a `literal` command using Apaches FTPClient(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient) from Java? I need to issue this command before i FTP a file across:

```
literal site format=3.1nsml
```

So if i run it through command prompt it works fine, however there doesnt seem to be a way of doing it though the FTPClient in Java. Does anyone know a workaround?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `FTPClient.doCommand` method to execute custom command.